# Uploadify don't show upload button in internet explorer 11

Tags: uploadify, internet-explorer-11

Please use IE11 browse the link http://www.uploadify.com/demos/, you can see that IE11 don't show upload button, instead it show native upload input.

How can I solve the problem or the way to workaround it?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have Adobe Flash installed. I had the same issue with IE 11 and this fixed the issue. Hope this helps.